# export all products from magento 2 for import into magento 1.9 programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, export

I have finally come to realize that Magento 2 is a way to buggy and unusable. I have 30,000 products and 1500 categories. What tables do I need to export in order to bring them in Magento 1.9?

Also, are there any differences I need to know about? I know category paths are stored as text instead of primary keys in 1.9, anything else?

Comment: Magento2: `Got to System >> Export >> Entity type: products >> Format type: CSV ` export the product and import in magento1.9

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the export function in the magento2 Backend. Its pretty good giving you all content needed.

Then dive into Magmi https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ in order to import it back into Magento1.9

Comment: Hello, Thanks for responding. The Mag 2 export is ok, but it can't handle 30,000 products, i have tried many times and it just freezes. I think sql is the way to go

Comment: There are so many records and tables associated. so sounds like a hassle / fault-sesentive. I think this might be a great read to this: https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html

Comment: How about this: https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexport